# How to get an element if a condition is true in xpath

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xpath, inspect

I have an XML file like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div aria="location">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="transcript">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the `div` with `aria=" location "` if there is an element and if there is not an element with that condition get the `div` with `class=" transcript "`.
I check my XPath in the chrome inspect element tab and I want to work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XPath:

```
(//div[@aria='location']|//div[@class='transcript' and not(following::div[@aria='location'])])[1]
```

Explanation:

- `(` grouping

  - `//div[@aria='location']` find a `div` element with an `aria` attribute value `location`
  - `|` or
  - `//div[@class='transcript' and not(following::div[@aria='location'])]` find a `div` element with a `class` attribute value `transcript` and there is no `div` element with an `aria` attribute value `location` after it, in document order
- `)` end grouping
- `[1]` take the first result

the `following` check is necessary, because if we just used:

```
(//div[@aria='location']|//div[@class='transcript])[1]
```

then, if the `div` element with class `transcript` came before the `div` with `aria` `location` in document order, then the `div` with class `transcript` would be returned due to how XPath traversal works.